# Use PageMethod to update dropdown list

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, pagemethods

I need to populate a DropDownList with a List of objects returned from a server side method. Since this should not result in a page refresh I am using PageMethods. When I debug, I can see that onSuccess function is being called but the dropdown list is not getting populated. The list of objects is successfully being passed from the server side method as well. I cant find out what is going wrong.

```
     function onsuccess(studList)
    {

            var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlStud');
            var count = ddl.options.length;
            while (ddl.options.length > 0)
            {
                ddl.options.remove(0);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < studList.length; i++)
            {

                var option = document.createElement('<option value="' + studList[i].id + '">');
                document.getElementById('ddlStud').options.add(option);
                option.innerText = studList[i].StudName;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your for loop to:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < studList.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value= studList[i].id;
            option.innerText = studList[i].StudName;
            document.getElementById('ddlStud').options.add(option);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var e = document.getElementById('ddlStud')
  e.options.length = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');

    option.value = response[i].id;
    option.innerText = response[i].StudName;
    e.options.add(option);
  }
```

Comment: Can you also explain how your code above solves the problem.